# Picketlink gets null Document from

Tags: jboss, picketlink

Here is an excerpt from Picketlink Federation 2.5.4 SP4 class org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2AuthenticationHandler which shipped with Jboss 6.4 (no tag on picketlink.org github for 2.5.4 SP4?).  My problem is that the top line, request.getRequestDocument() returns null.  The object itself, request (SAML2HandlerRequest) looks fine (not null):

```
 public void handleStatusResponseType(SAML2HandlerRequest request, SAML2HandlerResponse response)
            throws ProcessingException {
        HTTPContext httpContext = (HTTPContext) request.getContext();
        ResponseType responseType = (ResponseType) request.getSAML2Object();

    (...)

    Document responseDocument = request.getRequestDocument();
            Element assertionElement =
                    DocumentUtil.getChildElement(responseDocument.getDocumentElement(),
                            new QName(JBossSAMLConstants.ASSERTION.get()));

            if (assertionElement != null) {
                try {
                    Document assertionDocument = DocumentUtil.createDocument();
                    Node clonedAssertion = assertionElement.cloneNode(true);

                    assertionDocument.adoptNode(clonedAssertion);
                    assertionDocument.appendChild(clonedAssertion);

                    String assertionAttributeName = (String) handlerConfig
                            .getParameter(GeneralConstants.ASSERTION_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);

                    if (assertionAttributeName != null) {
                        session.setAttribute(assertionAttributeName, assertionDocument);
                    }

                    session.setAttribute(GeneralConstants.ASSERTION_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, assertionDocument);
                } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
                    throw new ProcessingException("Could not store assertion document into session.", e);
                }
            }
```

FYI, the reason I need this document is is that as you see in the code, if the responseDocument is null, then the asserionElement is null.  And if the assertionElement is null, then my SAML token will not be in the HTTPSession under the key given, and that is what I need.

The identity provider is PingIdentity.  And tips or tricks on what could be going on here before I have to learn the whole PicketLink code base?

Thanks!

FYI my set up is jboss 6.4, with the picketlink it ships with (2.5.4 SP4), with PingIdentity for SAML tokens (IdP).  FYI, all is working in an SSO scenario from WebApp 1 to WebApp 2, the only thing is that I need to get the SAML token from the SSO session on WebApp 2....

Answer (score 0):

Got it ))), the PingIdentity IdP SP Connection, Browser SSO, Protocol Settings, I had "Encrypt the Entire Assertion".  Setting that to "None", fixes it and I get my token in the HTTP Session.  So... ...with PKI, we encrypt with public key (cert) and decrypt with private key (key).  So either picketlink did not have the right private key (but I think it did) or the two systems don't understand how to do this PKI encrypt/decypt...